# Search your Google+ conversations

Tags: google-plus

Google provides the dominant Internet search. Moreover, it puts forward its Google+ social network (discussions), particularly, converting every YouTube conversation into one. How do you connect these two powerful technologies, how do you search the discussions that you participated in Google+? I see that I can easily look up the Google mail discussions but not Google+ ones.

I Have discovered some [Notifications Log](https://plus.google.com/notifications/all) but fail to search it. Where is the list of all your Google+ conversations? I also see some [Activity Log](https://plus.google.com/apps/activities) but is seems far from being complete.